# How to convert capture video from camera to a string android?

Tags: java, android, video

I used the following code to capture video from camera.  How can I convert it to a Base64 string?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

// create a file to save the video
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

// set the image file name
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

// set the video image quality to high
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

// start the Video Capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert video to a String? What you are trying to achieve with that?

Comment: upload it to a sever

Comment: depending on your video size you may even encounter OutOfMemoryError, my advice would be to skip conversion

Comment: and upload it as video ???

Comment: you ca use multipart file upload

Comment: i'll give it a try but can you post me an example ??

Comment: follow this @radwa http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: i followed this tutorial and uploaded file succesfully when i selected from gallery https://androidmads.blogspot.com.eg/2016/06/upload-file-to-server-using-retrofit-in.html

Comment: but i need the path of file when i captured it from camera can you help me

Comment: @Nilabja i used your way and it works fine thanks but i have a new challenge can i compress the file and decompress it on server so i upload it quickly??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did use multipartupload from retrofit and works fine and with no errors and crashes